# filling masked tokens in a text using MLM

Tags: nlp, dns, large-language-model

I need to train my model on a specific domain, for eg. hospitality domain so that my model learns the domain specific vocabulary. then it should fill masked tokens in another text dataset with that vocabulary. I am doing it in python but the trained model is not learning the correct vocabulary. (I have used BERT as well as GPT2). either it is giving garbled filled sentences or unfilled original sentences as result

I am doing it in python (colab) but the trained model is not learning the correct vocabulary. (I have used BERT as well as GPT2). either it is giving garbled filled sentences or unfilled original sentences as result